# Use Excel to calculate usage of items and sub-items

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I have a complex problem and I hope someone can help me out.  I am trying to use excel to calculate inventory usage over a set period.  The inventory usage works for single items, however, I have compound items.  Items that are made up of sub items.  So when I do the calculation, I need to do the look up.  Here are the following tables:

```
Inventory Item | Uses Inventory item | Quantity
A                    S1                  1
A                    S2                  3
A                    S3                  2
A                    S4                  1
B                    S3                  2
B                    S4                  2
C                    S1                  3
D                    S2                  3
```

Then we have the transaction sheet.  This transaction sheet has the item, how much was sold, which inventory it was taken from, and time stamp.

```
Item Uses | Amt Sold | Inventory | Time
A             1         I1         11:00
B             4         I1         11:04
B             4         I2         11:04
C             2         I2         11:10
D             5         I1         11:12
S3            2         I1         11:21
S4            1         I1         11:23
S1            2         I1         11:25
E             1         I2         11:26
F             2         I1         11:26
G             3         I1         11:27
B             4         I2         11:32
A             1         I2         11:47
C             2         I1         11:59
D             5         I1         12:01
A             1         I2         12:02
E             1         I1         12:04
F             2         I1         12:05
```

What I really Need is to fill out the following table of quantity of all items used from 11:00 to 12:00 Exclusive per inventory.  So I need to fill out the table as the OUTPUT:

```
Item | In Inventory | Total Sold
A         I1             ?
B         I1             ?
C         I1             ?
D         I1             ?
S3        I1             ?
S4        I1             ?
S1        I1             ?
E         I1             ?
F         I1             ?
G         I1             ?
A         I2             ?
B         I2             ?
C         I2             ?
D         I2             ?
S3        I2             ?
S4        I2             ?
S1        I2             ?
E         I2             ?
F         I2             ?
G         I2             ?
```

I have the answers by manually sorting by inventory and doing two full tables, but it is so difficult to manage due to the fact that my full item database is 22k items in 6 different inventories.

I have been able to get the raw counts (non-linked items) using `SUMPRODUCT` in excel.  I cannot figure out how to calculate out the linked item usage such that if I have 1 item sold of item A,  I have also sold 1 items of S1, 3 items of S2, 2 items of S3, and 1 item of S4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best
Jon

Comment: Just a side-comment I guess, but based on the structure of the information and your analytical task this is typically the point where you convert from Excel to Access.

Comment: The output is in the last table.  @Smandoli I agree, but I need to be able to send it to people who are not access savy but can understand excel documents.

Comment: Added tag `hierarchical data`. Note if your BOMS (bills of materials) go more than one layer deep, your solution will be correspondingly complicated. Can you clarify your data by arranging the white space? The last table is especially difficult to interpret.

Comment: Could you possibly insert a bar or something in the first table to aid legibility?

Comment: Take a look at installing the PowerPivot add-in for excel (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-pivot-add-in-HA101811050.aspx). It provides the ability to create relationships between tables and increase reporting capabilities. Just be warned that there is a bit of a learning curve...

Comment: Corrected some of the tables to be more legible.  Also @guitarthrower I will look at what you posted.  Thanks! Pnuts look at the last table that is now more legible.  That is the output.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Possibly what pnuts means is that the last table would be more helpful with results in place of all the `?` characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that complicated with the way your data is set up. Just usage of the `SUMIFS` formula (essentially the same as `SUMIF` but with multiple criteria)

Assuming that your second table above is on a sheet called `transaction`, with the `Item Uses` data in column A. And your output table on a sheet called `output` starting in cell `A3`. On the `output` sheet cell `B1` has the start time, and cell `B2` has the end time.

With all that in mind, the following formula (copied down your table) should do the trick.

```
=SUMIFS(transaction!B:B,transaction!A:A,A4,transaction!C:C,B4,transaction!D:D,">="&$B$1,transaction!D:D,"<="&$B$2)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just had to change the way I was calculating it.  Perfect solution @guitarthrower